# How do I do case-insensitive grouping with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I have a data frame with a `Factor` type column called `City`. It has valued like `New York` and `NEW YORK`.

When I run this code:

`group_by(dataframe, City)`

I get this result:

```
City, Value
New York, 12
NEW YORK, 100
```

I want the `City` grouping to be case-insensitive so it will put `New York` and `NEW YORK` in the same category.

Can I do this with `dplyr`?

Comment: Use `group_by(tolower(City))`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré that's works. If you make this an answer, I will mark it correct once stack overflow allows me. For a bonus, how can I put them in the category 'New York'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to `group_by` uniformed "city" categories, you could use `stri_trans_totitle` from the `stringi` package

From the documentation:

> With `stri_trans_totitle`, if word `BreakIterator` is used (the default),
>   then the first letter of each word will be capitalized and the rest
>   will be transformed to lower case.

For example:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Category = stringi::stri_trans_totitle(City)) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number())
```

Would give:

```
#Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
#Groups: Category [2]
#
#        City Value   Category    rn
#      (fctr) (int)      (chr) (int)
#1   New York    12   New York     1
#2   NEW YORK   100   New York     2
#3 NeW JerSey   123 New Jersey     1
#4 NEW JERSEY   111 New Jersey     2
```